# Prepare ill-fully pre-formatted text from an immutable resource for HTML/CSS rendering

Tags: php, html, css, regex, user-interface

Problem:

- Multiple text-fields in our database –may– contain pre-formatted text intended to
  display an ASCII-art or graph written with a proportional font.
- They contain lines the length of a paragraph (which we want to wrap)
- ¡¡¡ It is not an option to change the fields in DB !!!

Issues:

- Wrapping will destroy the intended 'ASCII-art'
- Rendering with `white-space: pre; overflow-x: auto;` CSS will cause very long lines and apply a very UI-unfriendly horizontal scroll.
- We use a different font to render than the user did when committing this content; so we cannot be sure of accurate rendering.

Solution intended:

- Present the proportionally pre-formatted text, as well as we can, using PHP on the backend and HTML/CSS on the frontend without changing the source data.

Question:

- Is there a better way to solve this in a non-elaborate manner, accepting that our input is `falsy`?

`$myPreFormattedText`:

```
##IgnorantB----dGraph with a very long single-line paragraph

"Anim Muji labore Marylebone concierge qui et eu, dolor culpa proident joy est elegant. Sharp perfect eiusmod Toto soft power excepteur voluptate business class quality of life enim ea. Flat white craftsmanship exquisite exercitation conversation. Washlet destination nostrud, sint aute bulletin elegant. Bureaux uniforms flat white Gaggenau occaecat Ettinger Porter enim dolore bespoke Fast Lane artisanal in. Airport Melbourne non eu magna vibrant first-class the highest quality id alluring in Ettinger. Anim handsome enim Boeing 787, Singapore Winkreative concierge in smart exquisite Zürich sed do.

IgnorantB----dGraph:
11|
10|
9  |
8  |
7  |
6  |
5  |
4  |
3  |
2  |
1  |
    |__________________________________________
        |   1   |   2   |   3   |  4   |   5   |   6   |   7   |   8


Tadah, tadah, I'm so happy with myself
I MiSs Access to this application 2 much...
```

Here's what I've come up with so far:

PHP:

```
/**
 * Use this function to render fields that -could- contain graphs or ASCII-art to HTML.
 *   If input was created with a proportional font, render output the same, to come as close as it gets.
 * @param $input
 * @return string
 */
function reformatPreFormattedText($input)
{
    if (is_string($input)) {
        // New-line to <br />, so we do not need `white-space: pre;` in CSS
        $output = nl2br($input);
        // Replace `n` consecutive spaces with 1 space and n-1 `&nbsp;`
        $output = preg_replace('~(?<=\s)\s~', '&nbsp;', $output);
        // Replace ` &nbsp;` with `&nbsp;&nbsp;`
        $output = preg_replace('~ &nbsp;~', '&nbsp;&nbsp;', $output);

        return strval($output);
    }

    // If a logger is present, you might want to log an error here.
    return '';
}
```

SCSS:

```
pre-formatted-text {
    display: block;
    //   These fields sometimes contain graphs or ASCII-art that was created with proportional font.
    //   We choose the intention to render them as close as it gets, not using mono-space fonts.
    //   @see reformatPreFormattedText()
    //font-family: monospace;

    // Apply horizontal scroll to facilitate graphs that are too wide for the container
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<pre-formatted-text>
    <?php echo reformatPreFormattedText($myPreFormattedText); ?>
</pre-formatted-text>
```

I hope to help, but more so to improve.

Comment: I'm done editing my question to perfection ;-) 
But I now realize that the real problem with my solution is, that a graphically intended *line* of characters may contain singly-spaced 'words' (...) then the wrapping will –albeit– break the graphic (or would it not?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use some algorithm that reads the text line-by-line and performs some simple checks on them:

- If the line starts with whitespace — ASCII art

  (Text rarely starts with whitespace.)
- If the line contains three (two) or more consecutive spaces — ASCII art

  (Text should not contain ≥ 3 consecutive spaces or tabs.)
- It the line contains only `[a-zA-Z0-9.,?!]` and whitespace — text
- …
- otherwise — ASCII art

I don't include any code because you will probably have to add more conditions or modify them to work better with your input.

---

Output this into series of `<pre>` (ASCII art: no-wrap) and `<p>` (text: wrap) tags. You can style `<pre>` to use proportional font:

```css
.prop-pre {
  font-family: sans-serif
}
```

```html
<pre class=prop-pre>Text text text text<pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Certainly sheds some light on what I'm not seeing. "I'll be back" ;-)